# Integrating Frontend (Vue.js, React and Angular) with Kafka as part of event driven architecture microservices

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, architecture, frontend

This is an architecture related question. I am exploring a new architecture/paradigm (real-time event driven) where the Frontend (could be vue.js, angular or react) calls multiple rest services that integrates with distributed streaming platform such as kafka.

I struggle to put this together. Reason below.

1. For simple operations on the Front end, which does not involve a state change, HTTP GET API calls would suffice - no need for Kafka.
2. For operations with state change, such as updating something, HTTP POST calls are required -- this is where Kafka might come in handy.

However, I also know of folks who have used websockets to resolve this.

How then can I leverage Kafka fully in relation to making the Frontend and the Backend a truly Event Driven Architecture?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a three tier app.

Kafka is your backend tier for data storage.

Some API layer exists to perform RPC. Kafka Streams Interactive queries could be used to create key-value store KTables for get-by-id type queries.

Your API layer also can run an active Kafka consumer thread which pushes messages into a websocket or as SSE messages.

Your web application will open and subscribe to the websocket and use JS to update the DOM.

User input on the site can send POST or GET back to the API.

The API layer will poll or push to (other) Kafka topics